# Compare Text from Speech to text in a Text View

Tags: android, speech-to-text

Brief description of Application

The user see a TextView that has a word. The user will click on an Button that will trigger the Speech To Text API and say the word given on the TextView. Now i need to match text from speech to text in textview.

Suppose text in text view is "Hello How are you"

text from speech to text Api is "Hello How are you"

I know we can match like

```
if (string1.equals(string2)){

}
```

But i don't want to match like whole string. I want to match each character of string one by one.

If character matched then color of matched character will be green else it will  be red.

Answer (score 0):

Checked out and came up with something like this:

```
String viewText = textview.getText();
String spokenText; //define yourself

for (int i = 0; i <= viewText.length(); i++) {
    char letter = viewText.charAt(i);
    char spokenLetter = spokenText.charAt(i);
    if(letter==spokenLetter) {
       //proceed further
    }
    else { 
        // return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gourav..i will implement above logic and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can make an empty linear layout in your xml with a horizontal orientation and add each letter dynamically after comparing in a different textView forexample something like:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int i = 0;
for(char a: string1.toCharArray()){
char b = string2.charAt(i);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
if(a == b){
tv.setText(String.valueOf(a);
tv.setColor(Color.GREEN);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(tv);
}else{
tv.setText(String.valueOf(a);
tv.setColor(Color.RED);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(tv);
}
i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate trough a string and check every char that whay.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string s = "peace";
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my answer cus i thought this would be better ;)

Comment: Do you know any other approach ?

Comment: You could also try an dictionary but it all comes to the same in the end. loop trough it. so no. not realy sorry. Not saying there ain't no other options. this is just the only one i can think of right now

Comment: @Gino I think the code should be in `Java` or `Kotlin` because the question is tagged     [tag:android] :)

Comment: That could be very true, but the tought behind the solution stays the same haha

Comment: That seems fine